# DHCP Server received Discover mesage but not responding with Offer mesage

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2019, dhcp-server

I using DHCP (windows server 2019 standard) for multiple scopes witch DHCP relay is Cisco 3750 L3 switch.

For the first time, it's working normally but after about 8 hours the DHCP server received discover message but not response with offer message (pls see in [statistics picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsxJJ.png) below).

Here is wireshark capture file for DHCP traffic, pls give me some suggestion

Thank you

Comment: What does the DHCP server log show?

Comment: Thank you, DHCP server log is normally, just information log there is no error log.

I try to disable DHCP filter and it's worked

Answer (score 0):

I try to disable DHCP filter and after that it's working normally, I don't know but it's work :D